# Java 8 method reference does not start thread?

Tags: java, java-8

Why does a method reference not start a thread in this example?

```
package example;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class ESMethodReference {
    int i1, i2, result = 0;

    ESMethodReference(int i1, int i2){
        this.i1 =i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    public Runnable calculate(){
        System.out.print("In calculate()");
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                result += i1 + i2;          
                System.out.print(" creating result");
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        ESMethodReference es = new ESMethodReference(1, 1);

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            executorService.submit(es.calculate());
            Thread.sleep(100);  // Allow new thread to run      
            System.out.println("\tes.calculate() result incremented " + es.result );

            executorService.submit(es::calculate);
            Thread.sleep(100);  // Allow new thread to run      
            System.out.println("\tes::calculate result NOT incremented " + es.result );
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Output:
In calculate() creating result  es.calculate() result incremented 2
In calculate()  es::calculate result NOT incremented 2
In calculate() creating result  es.calculate() result incremented 4
In calculate()  es::calculate result NOT incremented 4

Comment: When you are passing a method reference, the executor will execute the method in another thread and that's it. Which means that `calculate` is called in the other thread and the result silently discarded.

Comment: `es::calculate` is a `Runnable` that, when called, will invoke `es.calculate()`.  But it stops there, nothing then calls `.run()` on that.

Comment: Besides your failure to actually invoke the code with `es::calculate`, using `Thread.sleep` is not sufficient to see the result. It may happen that you see the expected result, but that’s not guaranteed. The executor’s thread may need longer than the specified number of milliseconds and [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) clearly says that it hasn’t any synchronization semantics; the code may have run without you seeing the new result. The `Future` returned by `submit` allows you to wait correctly.

Answer (score 12):

Because those are different things - passing `es::calculate` is the same as passing:

```
new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         es.calculate();
     }
}
```

Which, obviously, is not the same as:

```
new Runnable() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         es.calculate().run();
     }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I’m pretty sure es::calculate is equivalent to `new Callable<Runnable>() { return es.calculate(); }`, since there is a return type involved.  The exact matching algorithm for this case isn’t clear to me, even after reading [the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13) several times…

Comment: @VGR interesting but why would that confuse you? `es::calculate` can't be a `Runnable` since it returns a type; it can't be the second method that takes a `Runnable, T`, so the only one left is `Callable` - which fits...

Comment: @Eugene: references to methods returning a value are still suitable for a `Runnable`, as the result can be dropped, e.g. `executorService.submit((Runnable)es::calculate);` is valid Java code.

Comment: @VGR: You have to look at [§15.12.2.5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5). It says that for explicitly typed lambda expressions and exact method reference expressions, a functional interface type is more specific than another functional interface type if all parameter types match and the return type of the second is `void`.

Answer (score 5):

When you call `es.calculate()` it returns a `Runnable` with the code

```
public void run() {
    result += i1 + i2;          
    System.out.print(" creating result");
}
```

When you pass a method reference `es::calculate`, the code run will be

```
System.out.print("In calculate()");
return new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        result += i1 + i2;          
        System.out.print(" creating result");
    }
};
```

There's a difference between executing the return value of a method, and executing a method itself through a method reference.

Comment: Thanks, couple of questions...
1) Could you point me to the documentation re. this?
2) you mean es:calculate instead of es:calculate()

Comment: Err, yes `es::calculate` of course. I'm not sure what kind of documentation you're looking for, the basic docs for method references, functional interfaces, lambdas etc. or something else?

Answer (score 3):

```
executorService.submit(es::calculate);
```

is equivalent to

```
executorService.submit(() -> es.calculate());
```

which is not the same as

```
executorService.submit(es.calculate());
```

The former asynchronously creates the `Runnable` (without executing it) while the latter asynchronously executes (a distinct instance of) the same `Runnable`.

As a side note, you should probably avoid naming your method “*calculate*” if it only creates the task without calculating anything. If it was named `createTask()` for example, it would make it more obvious that the following does not calculate anything:

```
executorService.submit(es::createTask)
```

Or, if you made the method actually calculate the result:

```
public void calculate(){
    System.out.print("In calculate()");
    result += i1 + i2;
    System.out.print(" creating result");
}
```

then the call with the method reference would work as you expected it.